# Gradle build error -com.android.ide.common.internal.loggederrorexception failed to run command

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dex

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "paxcel.com.acceleromtermapping"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/parquet-hadoop-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/parquet-column-1.2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
    compile files('libs/junit.jar')
}
```

and Top-level build file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Error-

```
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Paras\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Paras\Documents\Android Studio Projects\AcceleromterMapping\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Paras\Documents\Android Studio Projects\AcceleromterMapping\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="paxcel.com.acceleromtermapping" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="paxcel.com.acceleromtermapping.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="paxcel.com.acceleromtermapping.WebViewD3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_web_view" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I searched for the problem they said that this is because of the same library with different versions added but it's not so. I am not able to find the reason?
Please Help.

Comment: Did you try geadle clean first?

Comment: @Raffaele yes but it did't worked

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is related with the 65k methods identifier limit of a dex file. To understand if this is the problem insert the line related with multidexing in your build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Then add the following line the application tag in your manifest (if you don't have a custom application class)

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you have a custom application extend MultidexApplication instead of Application.

Comment: I added the dependencies but it did't worked. I edited the question and added the manifest file also please check if something to be done with manifest.

Comment: it's now saying package R does not exist

Comment: Did you put in the manifest the line I wrote android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" In the tag application? Anyway the problem about the R class should be resolved if you clean the project

Comment: it this doesn't still work, you can try to add always in your build.gradle file this part:
android {
   ...
   dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
   }
}